# PHP add one day after strtotime

Tags: php, date, addition, strtotime

I have code like this

```
<?php
//current day is 2015-02-28
date_default_timezone_set ("Europe/Warsaw");

$data_to_do= date("Y-m-d 12:00:09",strtotime("+ 1 day"));
$number_of_day = idate('w', strtotime($data_to_do));

if($number_of_day=="0"){ // then send in monday
$data_to_do=date($data_to_do,strtotime("+1 day"));

}
echo "$number_of_day ". "$data_to_do it should be 02.03.2015";

?>
```

First adding day do current data works fine, but when i try to add another day to this one i have no changes.

I try to check if next day is sunday if yes set data to monday.

Comment: There are many similar Questions on SO [http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PHP+add+one+day+after+strtotime+-+Stack+Overflow](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PHP+add+one+day+after+strtotime+-+Stack+Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Well, isn't it simply that either should specify *+2 day* ? Or you can also do this : `$data_to_do=date($data_to_do,strtotime("+1 day", $data_to_do));` .

Answer (score 0):

Try with DateTime:

```php
$date = new DateTime('tomorrow 12:00:09', new DateTimezone('Europe/Warsaw'));
if (!$date->format('w')) {
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/294429)</kbd>